# Crystal Report showing HTML text, but the bullets don't show. Why?

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, formatting

I'm getting data out of a SQL-Server nvarchar(3000) field, which is formatted as html, displaying it in Crystal Reports 11.  The data is being saved as bullets, and if I pull out the data and drop it in a text file with an html extension, it shows the bullets.  But from Crystal, it does not.  I get the new line, but no bullets.

The field that is saved looks like this:

```
<HTML><BODY><DIV STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Tahoma;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:11;color:#000000;"><DIV><DIV><P><SPAN>This is a bulleted list</SPAN></P><UL><LI><P><SPAN>One</SPAN></P></LI><LI><P><SPAN>Two</SPAN></P></LI><LI><P><SPAN>Three</SPAN></P></LI></UL><P><SPAN /></P></DIV></DIV></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

And in Crystal, it looks like this:

```
This is a bulleted list 
One 
Two 
Three
```

In other words, no bullets.  Why not?

Comment: What happens if you trim `<LI><P><SPAN>One</SPAN></P></LI>` down to `<LI>One</LI>` ?

Comment: I don't have a lot of control over how the data is saved (app in C#.net, some sort of toolbar and text editor box).  However, I edited the data in the database, and that did not make a difference.  It did still show correctly in the app, still had no bullets in Crystal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For whatever reason, Crystal Reports has only ever supported a subset of HTML tags.  According to [this forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1209306.aspx), bullets are not one of them.

For posterity's sake, here is the purported list of supported HTML tags:

```
html
body
div (causes a paragraph break)
tr (causes only a paragraph break; does not preserve column structure of a table)
span
font
p (causes a paragraph break)
br (causes a paragraph break)
h1 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & twice default size)
h2 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 1.5 times default size)
h3 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 9/8 default size)
h4 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold)
h5 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/6 default size)
h6 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/8 default size)
center
big (increases font size by 2 points)
small (decreases font size by 2 points if it's 8 points or larger)
b
i
s
strike
u
```