# Superscript in Crystal reports formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to make part of array text into superscript inside my formula field. I tried rendering the field as HTML with a  tag but it seems it is not supported. Following did not work

```
numberVar array arr:=["1<sup>st</sup>"];
```

Is there a way round this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Crystal Reports doesn't support superscript at all, not for HTML (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983262/crystal-report-showing-html-text-but-the-bullets-dont-show-why/3983352#3983352) for supported tags if interested), or for RTF.

Off the top of my head, you would need two separate textboxes to achieve this effect, with the "st" text at a higher Y-position than the "1" to get "1<sup>st</sup>".

Comment: Thanks Bobby, I gave up the 'tag' idea & opted for your solution instead.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out Crystal Reports works with superscript, only the same way as [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819895/how-to-write-superscript-upper-index-in-visual-studio) does. Just copy/paste one of these: ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰