# How to show Superscript numbers in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, superscript

I have this crystal report which showing superscript data.
I have tried ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰ characters. ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819895/how-to-write-superscript-upper-index-in-visual-studio)) But only ¹²³ showing correctly.

Those are units. needed like this: "10⁶ / µL". but in crystal report, It shows as "106 / µL".

***Data coming from MSsql.

how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: [ask]. Perhaps you can tell a little bit more.

Comment: Is the text that needs to be a superscript predictable in such a way that it could be separated into a different column in your SQL query data set?

Comment: Yes. It is a master data. actually, those are units. needed like this: "10⁶ / µL". but in crystal report, it shows as "106 / µL".

Comment: If you can separate the string into 3 pieces of data in your data set, then you use 3 fields to display the data.  The `10` goes in the first with right justification to account for varying lengths of the string, then the `6` goes in the second field.  The second field should be a much smaller font size, with its top edge aligned to the first field's top edge so that it prints as a superscript.  Then the third field contains the `/ µL`.  Its a bit rough on the display, but its the only way I know to do this with database values.