# What HTML tags are supported in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: html, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I know by right clicking some text fields in Crystal Reports you can tell Crystal to render that report as `HTML` (See screenshots below). I'm wondering what the possible tags available in those fields is and what CSS/styling capabilities there are. Thanks!

[image: Right Click text field]

Right click a field and select "Format Field"

[image: Text Interpretation]

Click the Paragraph Tag and the Text Interpretation combo box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crystal Report showing HTML text, but the bullets don't show. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983262/crystal-report-showing-html-text-but-the-bullets-dont-show-why)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this in [a forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1209306.aspx). Not sure about it's validity, but it seems legit.

It appears that Crystal Reports only supports a small subset of HTML tags and attributes.

**The supported tags are:**

- `html`
- `body`
- `div` (causes a paragraph break)
- `tr` (causes only a paragraph break; does not preserve column structure of a table)
- `span`
- `font`
- `p` (causes a paragraph break)
- `br` (causes a paragraph break)
- `h1` (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & twice default size)
- `h2` (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 1.5 times default size)
- `h3` (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 9/8 default size)
- `h4` (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold)
- `h5` (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/6 default size)
- `h6` (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/8 default size)
- `center`
- `big` (increases font size by 2 points)
- `small` (decreases font size by 2 points if it's 8 points or larger)
- `b`
- `i`
- `s`
- `strike`
- `u`

**The supported attributes are:**

- `align`
- `face`
- `size`
- `color`
- `style`
- `font-family`
- `font-size`
- `font-style`
- `font-weight`

Not sure about CSS. I'm pretty sure you can't do any styling beyond what you see here.

Comment: some font size will be set 1 to 7 only, example : "Batch : " + "<font size=6>" + {tbl_Student_Info.Batch} + "</font>"

Comment: "text-align: justify;" is supported?