# HTML database value in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have html values stored on a table under varchar type. They are appearing on the report but the HTML is stripped. I've declared the text interpretation to HTML also but it still doesn't render bold, underline, font style or any basic tags. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This might be useful to you: http://forums.asp.net/post/3369852.aspx

Comment: Thanks but I found that, not what I'm looking for. I need to know how to make the HTML that's pulled from the DB render correctly. I've changed the text interpretation, which I thought would allow for those tags to be rendered correctly. However, it stripped all tags and formatted the HTML value into the style that is declared by CR for the text object. Using the default values for font, style, size, etc.

Comment: CR's HTML interpretation can be finicky, but it should still be able to handle the basics like bold and underline. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791321/what-html-tags-are-supported-in-crystal-reports-2008).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I now have HTML showing up correctly, it was the Editor control from AJAXControlToolkit that was causing the error and the way it was encoded.

However, now I have come across an issue with IE8/IE9 and decoding the value and it rendering on the CR correctly. Bold, underline, italics work but not font-size, font-face, font-color.

Everything works fine in FireFox, Chrome, and IE10.