# Crystal report handling HTML table

Tags: html, crystal-reports

As far as I know, Crystal report has a lot of limitation on interpreting HTML tags. I have also seen the supported tags list provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791321/what-html-tags-are-supported-in-crystal-reports-2008). However, I have `tr` and `td` tags and I cannot avoid using it.

Is there anything I can do in between the HTML and Crystal Report so that table can be created?

Sample Data

```
<p>Your tenses are a bit confused here. 
   For next piece of writing, write everything in past tense. Set all your 
   story with &ldquo;Last Sunday&rdquo; to get used to recounting in past 
   tense first.</p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>look</td>
            <td>looked</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cook</td>
            <td>cooked</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bless</td>
            <td>blessed</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: can you take HTML as the datasource connection?

Comment: @Siva the html is data i get from database.

Comment: can you post sample data that you get from database?

Comment: @Siva I've posted the sample data. It's just some regular HTML

Comment: Is this code coming from field in database? then you are trying to create a table in formula field on crystal reports and to the extent I know this is not possible...Also I would like know what is your exact requirement in crystal reports?

Comment: @Siva Yes. I did some research and I could not find any solution up till now.   The customer requested that one of the fields in the form needs to have a dynamic table.

Comment: This is not the way to create a table in crystal reports... you need to play around using lines and columns to create a table and I am sure it will work

Comment: @Siva I get what you mean but the customer requested a dynamic table. Can crystal report create dynamic table with lines and columns?

Comment: You can use cross tabs for dynamic table purpose

Comment: @Siva Thanks. Will have a look on it.