# Crystal Reports Ignores HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

Even though on a field I entered HTML text interpretation:

[image: Paragraph - Text Interpretation]

Even though my report uses valid tags as mentioned here: [What HTML tags are supported in Crystal Reports 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791321/what-html-tags-are-supported-in-crystal-reports-2008?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) my report is not generating HTML but just renders the tags out.

When the report renders I see the tags as static text:

```
<p>
  TEST
</p>
<p>
  <b>TEST</b>
</p>
<p>
  <u>TEST</u>
</p>
```

Why won't it show HTML?  Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"<p>"+
  TEST+
"</p>"+
"<p>"+
 " <b>"+TEST+"</b>"+
"</p>"+
"<p>"+
  "<u>"+TEST+"</u>"+
"</p>"+
```

Comment: The `<p>Test</p>` logic comes from the database so are you saying in the database it should have a value of `"<p>" + TEST + "</p>"`

Comment: Yes for HTML to work it should be in the given format