# Conditional Formatting Char vs Numeric in String

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to do some simple formatting in crystal reports like:

```
String:

   John Smith 212-212-2121
```

Where the A-Z would be one color and 0-9 would be a different color

I tried this

```
 if NumericText ({myString})
   then crRed else crNavy
```

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: you want one string with two diffrent color in one lable or textbox or Column? if they are two column that its possible.

Comment: Does one field contain the name and a second contain the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't have multiple colors in a single string.

You've got a couple of ways of doing this, but they're both kind of clunky, and your string as-is will need to either be parsed or reformatted.

1. Split your string into two separate formula fields.  Color the name field the appropriate color, and the phone number field with the appropriate color, and stick both of these fields into another textbox field.  It should look something like this crudely drawn example:

   `[ [Name formula field] [Phone formula field] ]`
2. Change your string to use HTML, and then format your textbox to use a Text Interpretation of HTML.  I can't say this will work 100%, though, because [Crystal Reports only supports some HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983262/crystal-report-showing-html-text-but-the-bullets-dont-show-why/3983352#3983352).

   In any case, your new string would look something like:

   `< font color='red'>John Smith< /font> < font color='blue'>212-212-2121< /font>`

Comment: I gave the html a go but it doesn't seem to work, seems to be a very limited subset of html.  I was trying to avoid splitting it as its all ready coming out of a function but I think I'm going to have to go that route.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that they are two fields, embed both in a Text Object.  You'll be able to change the text formatting of each field to be the desired color.

Another approach: place both fields on the canvas; color as desired.  Add a Text Object to the canvas.  Drag each field to the Text Object.  This should retain the formatting, but I haven't tested it.

It you need to split the text into name and number create two formula fields.  Once created, follow the steps listed earlier.

Comment: No its one string in the DB.  I actually gave a rather simplified example